# Textures disappear in BGE Playmode, but colliders are still there?

Tags: materials, game-engine, transparency

I have built a village level in Blender Game Engine, and up till today all was good. However now my Grass texture and my wood texture become Transparent when I enter the Play mode, but the mesh still has collision.

Zipped level: [The level and all associated textures](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwmWa-IlNzrzSjlxSnRoa01LOHc/view?usp=sharing)
<sub>Play Mode on the left vs. Material View on the right</sub>
[image: Play Mode vs. Material View]

Update: It seems to be object specific, not material specific.

Comment: I looked through your blend and there was nothing wrong. Everything displayed properly, even when playing the game from your cycles scene. Does that file display wrong for you?

Comment: Check to make sure that to file path to your grass texture is correct, this could be the reason David was able to play, but not you. Sometimes blender has trouble keeping track of files if to much activity is going on. Recreate the texture if needed.

Comment: @David Ya, in the picture you can see the BGE with playmode on the left, and object mode on the right

Comment: @VinceScalia I checked the path, then tried with a different texture but I got the same negative result.

Comment: This is only certain textures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the cause of the problem, but simply replacing the material with a new one worked, even if all the settings are tha same as the previous material.

Answer (score -1):

I had joined a bunch a walls during a  process of optimization and I had somehow had an object that was set to invisible under physics tab.!